# How to pass values of selected checkboxes from multiple pages in Data Table

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, checkbox

I have records in bootstrap data table which has pagination and each record will have a checkbox. Let say when I click some checkboxes in page 1 and some checkboxes in page 2, the form will only pass value of checkbox in page 2. How can I retrieve the checkbox values from page 1?Any help is much appreciated.

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    btn = $("#btnCutoff");

  //structure of table
  var table = $('#table').DataTable({

            "bLengthChange": false,
            "pageLength": 5,
            "bFilter": false 

  });

//disable button when no records are selected
btn.attr("disabled","disabled");

 checkboxes.on('click', function(event) {
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        btn.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        btn.attr("disabled",!checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    }
}); 

$("#table tbody").on("click",".clickable-row", function (event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

when clicks button, it will go to a javascript function

```
function doEnquiry(){
   var f = document.frm;
   f.method = "POST";
   f.action = "test.jsp";
   f.target = "_self";
   f.submit();
}
```

and I want to assign the checkbox values to here

```
String curr[] = request.getParameterValues("chkTest");
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every checkbox click if the checkbox is checked create a hidden field to store its value.You can rely on the hidden field values to capture all the checkbox values you want and can easily access them on the server side instead.

```
checkboxes.on('click', function(event) {
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        btn.removeAttr('disabled');
        $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="fieldname" value="'+this.value+'" />');
    } else {
        btn.attr("disabled",!checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    }
});
```

Comment: so, on the server side, i just request the "fieldname" right?

Answer (score 1):

***Jquery code***

```
   $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#viewlist').DataTable();  
    $("#button").click(function() {  
        var chcklist = new Array();  
        var oTable = $('#viewlist').dataTable();  
        var rowcollection =  oTable.$("#emp_name:checked", {"page": "all"});  
        rowcollection.each(function(index,elem) {  
            chcklist.push($(elem).val());    
        });  
        $.post(
            "../accounts/updateSalaryHold.jsp", 
            {list: chcklist}, 
            function (values) {  }
        );  
    });  
});
```

**jsp page Code**

```
String[] arrayVal = request.getParameterValues("list[]");
```

Comment: a `$` is missing at Line 3. and in case if your answer may solved it, the author would appreciate it to see some explanation